# R package rcites: bulk enquiry using functions "spp_taxonconcept" and "map"

Tags: r, map-function

I have a csv file with a list of bird species (heading=Sci.Name) which I would like to bulk enquire their CITES appendix listing using the "spp_taxonconcept" function in the package rcites.

After setting the token, loading the csv file and all the packages needed I use the following code to generate the result in the column named "results":

```
bird.cites<-mutate(bird.cites,results=map(Sci.Name,spp_taxonconcept(taxonomy="CITES")))
```

which returns the following error msg:
x argument "query_taxon" is missing, with no default

Elements of the object "Sci.Name" was not passed to spp_taxaonconcept as the first argument, which should be query_taxon = "sci names of individual species" using the map function.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some syntax issues Try. -

```
bird.cites <- mutate(bird.cites,results=map(Sci.Name,spp_taxonconcept, taxonomy="CITES"))
```

which can also be written as -

```
bird.cites <- mutate(bird.cites, results = map(Sci.Name,~spp_taxonconcept(.x, taxonomy="CITES")))
```